# How to do a import statement in a python script that gets called from two different contexts

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I'm trying to import a file but I can only get it to work from one context at a time.

This my project structure:

```
.
├── module/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── script.py
│   ├── utilities1.py
│   └── utilities2.py
└── test.py
```

`script.py` is usually called externally directly it imports `utilities1.py`

`utilities1.py` imports `utilities2`.py

`test.py` Is a file that contains tests and includes both `utilities1.py` and `utilities2.py`

My question is how to do the import statement in `utilities1.py`
When I call it from `script.py` it needs to be

```
import utilities2
```

But when I call it from `test.py` that results in an error requiring it to be

```
import module.utilities2
```

Is there a way I can get the import statement right in both contexts?
Or do I need to change something structurally in my project?
Thank you :)

Comment: Do you not need an `__init__.py` at the top level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is being able to use `import utilities1` from test.py you could modify the search path of modules. [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) is the list of paths where the interpreter will look for modules to import. Do `print(sys.path)` and you'll see. You can also modify it while running your script.

For example, keeping with the file structure you described

```
# script.py

import utilities1
import utilities2

utilities1.show_myself()
utilities2.show_myself()
```

```
# utilities1.py

def show_myself():
    print("I'm utilities1")

def test_myself():
    print("Testing who I am... The answer: utilities1")
```

```
# utilities2.py

def show_myself():
    print("I'm utilities2")

def test_myself():
    print("Testing who I am... The answer: utilities2")
```

```
# test.py

import sys

sys.path.insert(1, "module")

import utilities1
import utilities2

utilities1.test_myself()
utilities2.test_myself()
```

In `test.py` I have inserted `module` in `sys.path` which is the relative path where the running script will to be looking into for modules `utilities1` or `utilities2`. That's why it is able to acess directly yo those two modules.

If that's not what you were trying to do, please explain further.